# How do you create a function to input two vectors to produce a matrix

Tags: r, math, matrix, vector, distance

Lets say I have 5 pairs of coordinates in vector form (x1,y1)(region1) , (x2,y2)(region2) and so on up to (x5,y5)(region5).
Now I want to find the distance of each region from each other. For instance , I take
distance, D = √[(i−)^2+(−)^2] between region i and j and the output will be a 5 by 5 matrix where each entry in the matrix(Dij) is the distance between the two regions.
[image]

For example, I have region 1 where its coordinate is (4,3) and region 2 (1,2). Then the distance between these two regions should be D = √10 and this should be in the entry of Dij where i =1 and j=2, hence D12 as seen in the above matrix.
I have attempted the code as seen below :

```
x=c(1,2,4,1,1)
y=c(4,3,1,2,2)
Distance = function(x,y){
D = sqrt(abs((x[i]-x[j])^2+(y[i]-y[j])^2))
A = matrix(0,nrow=5,ncol=5,T)
i = nrow(A)
j = ncol(A)
for (i in 1:5){
for (j in 1:5){
A[i][j] = D
}
}
return(A) 
}
```

Output:

```
Warning messages:
 1: In A[i] <- `*vtmp*` :
 number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

There were 20 of these warning messages. Sigh. I know my code is far from correct. Please help

Comment: I won't properly troubleshoot your function in a comment suffice to say that the calculations should be occurring inside the double loop and the indexing for `A` isn't correct.  R has a builtin distance function so I think you're just looking for `dist(cbind(x, y), diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE)`.

Comment: You can either accept the answer that solved your question or post your own instead of marking in the title

Comment: Alright,  I didn't notice it. Will remember that from now on. I'm quite new to stack overflow. Thanks for the friendly reminder. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has the following problems.

- the line defining D uses i and j even though they have not been defined at that point
- the line defining D uses abs(...) but the part within (...) is never negative so using abs is pointless
- if x[i], y[i] is the ith point then the length of x and y must the same so we should check for that.
- the line defining A hard codes 5 so the function can only work if the x and y have length 5.
- the fourth argument to matrix is T.  Never use T to mean TRUE.  Always write it out because T is a possible variable but TRUE can never be a variable name.
- it is pointless to specify byrow = TRUE when defining the matrix since every element is given the same value so the order does not matter.  In fact we don't have to fill in A at all since the loop later does that.
- i and j are defined as nrow(A) and ncol(A); however, right after that they are redefined so the original definitions are just thrown away and never used.  Those lines have no effect.
- the two loops hard code the upper limit as 5 so, again, the function will only work if x and y both have length 5.
- A[i][j] should be A[i, j]
- D is used in the loop but is defined outside the loop so every element of A[i,j] will be given the same value
- the code is not indented making it hard to read
- putting more spaces in the code would make it easier to read
- although it is not wrong to write return(A) just writing A would be sufficient to return it
- the question refers to the output but there is no output because the code never runs the function

Code--

```
Distance = function(x, y) {
  stopifnot(length(x) == length(y))
  n = length(x)
  A = matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    for (j in 1:n) {
      A[i, j] = sqrt( (x[i] - x[j])^2 + (y[i] - y[j])^2 )
    }
  }
  A
} 

# test
x = c(1, 2, 4, 1, 1)
y = c(4, 3, 1, 2, 2)
Distance(x, y)
##        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
## [1,] 0.0000 1.4142 4.2426 2.0000 2.0000
## [2,] 1.4142 0.0000 2.8284 1.4142 1.4142
## [3,] 4.2426 2.8284 0.0000 3.1623 3.1623
## [4,] 2.0000 1.4142 3.1623 0.0000 0.0000
## [5,] 2.0000 1.4142 3.1623 0.0000 0.0000
```

Note that this can be done more compactly using outer.

```
d <- function(i, j) sqrt((x[i] - x[j])^2 + (y[i] - y[j])^2)
n <- length(x)
outer(1:n, 1:n, Vectorize(d))
##        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
## [1,] 0.0000 1.4142 4.2426 2.0000 2.0000
## [2,] 1.4142 0.0000 2.8284 1.4142 1.4142
## [3,] 4.2426 2.8284 0.0000 3.1623 3.1623
## [4,] 2.0000 1.4142 3.1623 0.0000 0.0000
## [5,] 2.0000 1.4142 3.1623 0.0000 0.0000
```

Comment: Woah, honestly, I am really grateful that you took the time to point out my mistakes! Thanks for the help but I want to mention if using dist(cbind(x, y), diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE) in the middle of the function is supposed to make things faster?

Comment: Good idea.  `as.matrix(dist(cbind(x, y)))` gives the same answer as `Distance(x, y)` as it gives a matrix whereas `dist(cbind(x, y), diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE) ` returns an object of class "dist" .